# Things which can be done with MYSQL instead of involving PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, function

What are the must-know MYSQL functions (like IF etc..,) which every web developer should know?

Comment: The title was more interesting than the actual question :)

Comment: Question and the title actually means the same here, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite:

[`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

It allows me to bypass heavy PHP code to fetch data from one table, manipulate it and insert into another.

Answer (score 4):

i'd say:

```
CREATE VIEW .. AS SELECT
```

when i have querys that i use all the time, but it's not a function =P

Comment: This greatly removes dependence on complex ORMs.

Comment: @stillstanding - agree wholeheartedly

Answer (score 4):

Triggers and stored procedures offer much automation that involve only the SQL engine and this will significantly reduce the Web server's load and PHP code involved in data housekeeping.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite is "insert... on duplicate key update..." ;-)

Every string functions: concat, concat_ws, ... now().

GROUP BY functions: sum(), max(), count() + the wonderful group_concat()

JOIN clauses and VIEWs if you you are planning complex requests.

Well, in fact, the more you know MySQL (I mean, everything), the best.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite:

```
alter table child add Foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id);
```

Taking care of data integrity with foreign keys will reduce your code base a lot. Not mentionign MySQL is better at this than PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Some features that come to my mind:

- [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) if your Model involves tables with similar data:

  `(SELECT ...) UNION ALL (SELECT ...)`
- [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) and [NULLIF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)
- [RLIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for regular expression matching
- If you work with fulltext indexes:

  `... WHERE MATCH (field) AGAINST ('string')`

  (Also take a look at the [boolean matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html))
- [Memory tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)
- [INSERT DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-delayed.html)